# Why is my OnClickListener not triggering in Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment, onclicklistener

Am I missing something with the code ?

> ```
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
>         //btnButtonTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.btnOne2);
>         //btnButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
>
>
>         btnButtonTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.btnOne2);
>         //btnButtonTwo.setEnabled(true);
>         btnButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Y0U clicked da Button, INSIDE THE FRAGMENT!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             }
>         });
> return view;
> }
> ```
>
> [Fragment_blank.xml]
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".BlankFragment">
> <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" >
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnOne2"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:focusable="auto"
>
>         android:text="One" />
> </LinearLayout>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

I extracted the OnClickListener code onto a separate app in an attempt to isolate the problems.   The buttons should be responsive to clicking but its not. I'm not sure what is going on now!
Working project files is located here...
https://github.com/potpori-code/clicky/MyOnClicky.zip

```
[MainActivity.java]
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_blank);     
        loadFragment(new BlankFragment(), false);
     }

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean bool) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.layout.activity_main, fragment);
    if (bool)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what "The buttons should be responsive to clicking but its not." means. Have you attempted to debug your app to find the problem? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: In the fragment_blank.xml there is a button label One.  If clicking was initiated on the button it would triggered the OnClickListener in BlankFragment.java and display the toast message saying  "Y0U clicked da Button, INSIDE THE FRAGMENT!".   Right now it is not even triggering the OnClickListener after the One button was clicked.  I put breakpoints on the OnClick(View V) function inside of the OnClickListener in BlankFragment.java noting seem to trigger !?   Why is that ?  Please Advise.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Does the `onCreateView` itself get triggered? How is your fragment created?

Comment: The onCreateView in BlankFragment.java do not get triggered at all.  But the OnClick OnClickListener placed in the MainActivity.java will get triggered just fine.  My fragment was created by right clicked on the com.example.myclicky folder then New\Fragment\Fragment (Blank)

Comment: That's how you created the _file_. How do you create, instantiate, and add the Fragment to the Activity? https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add

Comment: In my original code I had a function called loadFragment that replaces the default activity_main layout with the fragment_blank layout. 
loadFragment is no longer used in my code.
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean bool) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.layout.activity_main, fragment);
    if (bool)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

Comment: In my mainActivity.java  OnCreate()
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);              
        loadFragment(new BlankFragment(), false);
    }

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding comments with code - it's extremely difficult to read.

Comment: Code added to the code viewer.

Comment: Review [the documentation for `replace()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) and compare that to what you're doing.